# How build Rest API with feathers js?

Tags: feathersjs

I have in my file server.js this code:

```
MongoClient.connect(url).then(db => {
  app.use('/users', service({
    Model: db.collection("Users"),

  }));
});
```

Now if i open "/users" all my users are displayed. I want to create service to give me one user by its Id . when i visit "/users/5" will give me the user who his id=5. Please who can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already built in. MongoDB uses [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) in `_id`. So if you take any `_id` property from the `/users` list and open `/users/<_id>` it will show that specific user.

For more information see the [basics guide](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/step-by-step/readme.html), the [services API](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html) (and how those [map to a REST API](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/rest.html#direct-connection)) as well as the [database adapter common API](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/common.html) and the [MongoDB adapter documentation](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/mongodb.html).